# How to remove all but the 26 letters, and . , ( ) ' " ? ! from a string in Python?

Tags: python, regex, string, parsing

I have :

```
string = 'Here it is, your gif! am a bot. [^(Report an issue)] ❤ that bot,I ❤ ur mom **YEET**  ,GOTTEM!"'
```

and I try :

```
string = re.sub(r'\W+', ' ', string)
```

and that gives me :

```
'Here it is your gif am a bot Report an issue that bot I ur mom YEET GOTTEM'
```

But I would like this :

```
'Here it is, your gif! am a bot. (Report an issue) that bot,I ur mom YEET ,GOTTEM!"'
```

Just the 26 letters, no numbers and only the most used symbols in this group: `.,()'"?!`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Make a character class of the things you accept (with `[]`) and invert it (with a leading `^`, making it `[^stuff]`):

```
string = re.sub(r'[^a-zA-Z.,()\'"?! ]+', '', string)
```

Comment: Thanks. I'll give it the green check when it lets me. But what do you mean by 'invert'? "invert it (with a leading ^"

Comment: @Renoldus: Normally, a character class matches any of the things in it, so `[a-z]` matches only lower case alphabetic characters. Putting the `^` at the beginning of the class means it matches everything *but* the things in it, so `[^a-z]` will match all characters *except* lower case alphabetic characters; it's "inverting" the set of things the class matches on.

Comment: I see. Knowing that will come in handy.

Answer (score 1):

Use this for your regex instead : `[^a-zA-Z?!.,()\'" ]+`

The brakets define a collection of elements you wish to select, the caret at the front defines the negation of what is inside.

Thus leaving you with

```
pattern = r'[^a-zA-Z?!.,()\'" ]+'
string = re.sub(pattern, ' ', string)
```

Comment: Inside a character class, you don't need to escape most punctuation; [per the docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#index-9): "Special characters lose their special meaning inside sets." About the only stuff that needs escaping (or careful placement) are `-` (must be first or escaped), `]` (must be first or escaped), `^` (must be escaped *only* if in first position), `\ ` (if it might otherwise make a recognized escape) and the quote character chosen for the string. Getting rid of the unnecessary backslashes makes it a lot easier to read.

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out, did not know! regex101.com told me it was valid so that was good enough for me ^^

Comment: I updated the answer to reflect that. Thank you @ShadowRanger, I learnt something !